# OBIEE 12.2.1.2 Admin - Manage Privileges - Disappearing Subject Areas

Tags: admin, business-intelligence, privileges, obiee

OBIEE 12.2.1.2 is running on linux environment.

Sometimes some of the subject areas are disappearing within manage privileges [image] - this did not happen with Obiee 11.x.

Only two subject areas are shown - however there are some more:
[image]

Restarting the server magically solves this problem, however this is extremely annoying. Investigating logiles did not help.

Ideas and suggestions are much appreciated

Comment: Is that a migrated catalog from 11 or a brand new one from 12?

Comment: Hi, catalog was migrated from 11. After restarting everything is fine.

Comment: No other permission issues on any other presentation catalog folder? Have you checked the .atr files on the disk once? Maybe you need to explicitly set the rights once across all your SAs so they're proper. You can do that by backing up the catalog , then dropping the approriate files plus .atr from the disk. The server will recreate them after startup.

Comment: Hi, I have not checked the .atr files yet.  I guess backing up the catalog is best done with "exportServiceInstance" and creating a .bar file (since I can grab all data and credentials, too)- however, I have also found the "archive" option in the catalog manager.

Comment: Both options are ok